# JAX-RS Provider randomly acts server-wide

Tags: java, jax-rs, wildfly, resteasy, provider

I need some help understanding how Resteasy messes up my registered Providers

I have 2 services, lets call them Scheduler and Process.
Process has a ClientRequestFilter annotated with @Provider that adds some headers to Rest Requests.
Scheduler regularly calls an entirely different service via Rest.It does not have a requestfilter, nor any dependency to Process.

Still, *sometimes* when I start my wildfly27 container that contains these Services, my Scheduler will permanently throw Exceptions, whose stacktraces contain the Filter of my Process. (The filter injects HttpServletRequest, which isn't available there )

Now as far as hours of googling got me, I think that all classes registered as providers are registered to the entire Resteasy runtime within wildfly, not just the specific deployment they're contained in.

Now what I dont understand is why this behaviour appears to be completely random. Sometimes the container and services start just fine, sometimes they have this issue. The order in which they are deployed seems to have no effect on this.
Undeploying the process which contains the requestfilter afterwards also does not change anything about this.

Removing the Provider annotation and instead listing the filter in the jakarta.ws.rs.ext.Providers file also had no effect.

It seems that a solution to this would be to manually register all resources and providers in the Application Class of the deployments, but I'm not really that fond of manually adjusting numerous services that run within the same wildfly server and copying every single rest resource there.
Manually registering providers to every single rest client is also out of the question for the same reason.

Can anyone clear up my confusion, and maybe even suggest a proper solution?
Thanks in advance

stacktrace:

```
jakarta.ws.rs.ProcessingException: org.jboss.weld.contexts.ContextNotActiveException: WELD-001303: No active contexts for scope type jakarta.enterprise.context.RequestScoped]
wildfly27_1   |     at deployment.scheduler.war//.scheduler.jobs.AbstractRestJob.execute(AbstractRestJob.java:61)
wildfly27_1   |     at deployment.scheduler.war//org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
wildfly27_1   |     at deployment.scheduler.war//org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
wildfly27_1   | Caused by: jakarta.ws.rs.ProcessingException: org.jboss.weld.contexts.ContextNotActiveException: WELD-001303: No active contexts for scope type jakarta.enterprise.context.RequestScoped
wildfly27_1   |     at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-client@6.2.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.filterRequest(ClientInvocation.java:767)
wildfly27_1   |     at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-client@6.2.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.invoke(ClientInvocation.java:499)
wildfly27_1   |     at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-client@6.2.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.invoke(ClientInvocation.java:71)
wildfly27_1   |     at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-client@6.2.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocationBuilder.get(ClientInvocationBuilder.java:198)
wildfly27_1   |     at deployment.scheduler.war//scheduler.jobs.RestGetJob.performRequest(RestGetJob.java:16)
wildfly27_1   |     at deployment.scheduler.war//scheduler.jobs.AbstractRestJob.execute(AbstractRestJob.java:45)
wildfly27_1   |     ... 2 more
wildfly27_1   | Caused by: org.jboss.weld.contexts.ContextNotActiveException: WELD-001303: No active contexts for scope type jakarta.enterprise.context.RequestScoped
wildfly27_1   |     at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getContext(BeanManagerImpl.java:628)
wildfly27_1   |     at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$DefaultContextualInstanceStrategy.getIfExists(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:89)
wildfly27_1   |     at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstance.getIfExists(ContextualInstance.java:63)
wildfly27_1   |     at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:87)
wildfly27_1   |     at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:105)
wildfly27_1   |     at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.generated.proxies.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getRemoteUser(Unknown Source)
wildfly27_1   |     at deployment.process.war//process.core.remote.RequestFilter.filter(RequestFilter.java:20)
wildfly27_1   |     at deployment.process.war//process.core.remote.RequestFilter$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.filter(Unknown Source)
wildfly27_1   |     at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-client@6.2.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.filterRequest(ClientInvocation.java:754)
wildfly27_1   |     ... 7 more
```

Comment: Can you post a stacktrace?

Comment: I can post one when I get back to work, but there really isn't anything useful to see there. It's just endless lines of wildfly/resteasy interceptor stuff and then 2 lines of my filter being called.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins added one
Currently pondering whether to just implement a requestfilter in all deployments instead. whatever resteasy does, the one defined within the deployment itself should always be prioritized. At least thats what I hope/think

Comment: What are you using to schedule jobs? It looks like the CDI context is not set. IoW what kind of executor are you using?

Comment: Im using the quartz scheduler. Jobs created by quartz arent CDI managed so that tracks (Class.newInstance() ). I can modify the job Factory to use CDi created instances (by CDI.current().select(xyz.class).get() ) However, the real issue is that the filter shouldn't be used in the first place.

Comment: It's hard to say what's really happening when the thread is created out of the scope of the container. Do you know the error is coming from a specific failure? The only way I'd be able to see what is happening is with a reproducer which I assume is nearly impossible. I'd highly suggest looking at Jakarta Concurrency for scheduling threads.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. The error itself occurs because the invoked RequestFilter injects HttpServletRequest, and the injections fails in the filter because there is no request to inject (since the actual call came from a scheduled thread). Why the filter is even invoked is my question so no clue there.

Transitioning to jakarta concurrency is not an option for us for several reason im afraid, I also cannot share a reproducer because the container and code rely on company internal resources.

Comment: In the end I just ended up removing the provider annotation and manually registering the filter to every restclient / restproxy (eclipse microprofile) via .register/@registerprovider in the wildlfy27 environment.
Fortunately, there weren't that many since there's a massive amount of calls/methods but not that many different targets, meaning they use the same client/proxy.

For some reason, wildfly10 still works fine even with the provider annotation in more than 5 deployments. I'm guessing something changed in resteasy between these versions.

Thanks for trying to help though!

Comment: I figured a reproducer would not be easy to do :) It would just be the only way I could see how the filter is getting registered. However, since it's coming from a deployment it should get discovered and added to the RESTEasy context. Given it is executed outside of a request, that's why the CDI context is out scope as you noted. I think your fix is the only way to do this. Even using a `ManagedExecutorService` would not work in this case. Sorry about the confusion there.